# AngularJS directive : compile template and watch scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I writing a pretty complex application on Angularjs. This is already big enough to confuse me. I research Angular deeper and I see my code is bad. 
I understand this concept:

```
 module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
     scope: {
             // scope bindings with '=' & '@'
            },                                                                                                                  
     template: '<div>Template string with binded {{ variables }}</div>',          
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            // Function with logic. Should watch scope.
            }
```

I have several problems:

- My template is complicated, I have part of template which going in the link function dynamically
- I need to append compiled template to the element, not to replace.
- With concept above my template are appended without any interpolation...

So my code is looking like that in simplified view:

```
module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
     scope: {
              var1: '@var1',
              var2: '@var2',
              var3: '@var3'
            },                                                                                                                  
     template: '<div>{{ var1 }} {{ var3 }}</div>',          
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              $('.someelement').on('event', function(){
                var2 = 'SNIPPET';  // Need to watch it
              }); 
              var3 = '<span>{{ var2 }}</span>';
            }
     })
```

My questions is:

**How to compile my template with scope variables?**

**How to watch scope variables?**

**Should I split my directive for two? If I should, how to do it in right way?**

Comment: if willing to use angular 1.4 , function for `template` was added that allows access to attributes  http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/guide/directive

Comment: @charlietfl, could you make your comment as a response with an example of code?

Comment: Am i wrong or could you avoid using jQuery mixed with angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think change your directive by :

```
 module.directive('createControl', function($compile, $timeout){
     scope: {
              var1: '=var1',
              var2: '=var2',
              var3: '=var3'
            },                                                                                                                  
     template: '<div>{{var1}} {{var3}}</div>',          
     link: function(scope, element, attrs){
              $('.someelement').on('event', function(){
                scope.var2 = 'SNIPPET';  // Need to watch it
              }); 
              /*I do not see what you want to do*/
              scope.var3 = $compile('<span>{{var2}}</span>')(scope);
            }
     })
```

Answer (score 9):

Angular 1.1.4 released in last few weeks added ability for `template`  to access attributes in directives:

Example:

```
app.directive('mytest',function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',    
   template:function( elem,attrs ){      
      return '<div>'+attrs.a+' '+attrs.b+'</div>';
    }
  }
});
```

```
<mytest a="Hello" b="World"></mytest>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/OGB7ZL42S9TJtoXPWFjj?p=preview)**</kbd>

See [directive docs for version 1.1.4](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/guide/directive)

Comment: Note sure if I had the same problem as the OP but this just saved me a whole heap of time thanks for posting.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out that the link you added for docs doesn't work directly linked to for whatever reason.  You have to go to [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api) and then search for 'directives' in the top right.